# Return view json response

Tags: laravel

I try to pass a return json to my view but I get an error who say that I didn't past all the variables objects to the view, the problem if I pass all the variables in my table I get all my web page in the table wish is no sense..

someone know how I could do?

here my controller:

```
public function searchEquipes(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->has('poule_id')) {

        $equipes = EquipePoule::where('poule_id' , $request->poule_id)->get();

        return response()->json([

            'table' => view("competitions/show", compact('equipes'))->render(),

        ]);

    }else {

        //nothing
    }
}
```

here my view:

```
@foreach($equipes as $equipe)

                                    <tr>

                                        <td><a href="{!! route('club.show', $equipe->equipe->structure->id) !!}">{{$equipe->equipe->structure->nom_structure}}</a></td>
                                        <td><a href="{!! route('equipe.show', $equipe->equipe->id) !!}">{{$equipe->equipe->lb_equipe}}</a></td>
                                        <td>{!! Form::text('nb_bonus') !!}</td>

                                    </tr>

                                @endforeach
```

here my script:

```
 <script>
        $('#poule').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url : 'search/equipes',
                dataType: "json",
                data : {
                    poule_id : document.getElementById('poule').value
                },

                success:function(data){

                    $('#equipes').html(data.table);

                }


            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are not returning the json response the right way try using

```
  return response()->json([$equipes]);


    success:function(data){

                //loop $equipes here

            }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply ! i would like to use the same table in my blade view inside the foreach ! if i do it like this i need to create again a table inside the script ;.. that's why i used return reponse view ! you know what i mean ?

Comment: You would either want to return the object to the blade view or return the JSON to the ajax call. Not both. Populate the table using javascript when the response is returned or just pass the object and loop through it in the view.